# Adding missing years?

Tags: r

i'm a new user and i need a lil help
My df looks like this

```
         y         v
 1    2000       1
 2    2003       3
 3    2005       3
 4    2006       6
 5    2009       1
 6    2011       1
 7    2013       3
```

I wanna add years that don't appear among the years vector and put it's approriate v value by 0's. Like 2001,2002..
 for instance;

```
         y         v
 1    2000       1
 2    2001       0
 3    2002       0
 4    2003       3
 5    2004       0
 6    2005       3
```

my first try was to create another vector using the library chron

here's my code,

```
 yy <- seq.dates(from="01/01/2000", to="12/31/2013", by="years")
 yy <- as.POSIXct(yy, f="%Y")
 yy <- format(yy, f ="%Y")
 pp <- rep(0, length=14)
 yp <- data.frame(cbind(yy, pp))
```

but since they don't have the same length, i couldn't replace the values from DF to yp when they years are the same!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `merge` for this:

```
DF <- read.table(text="         y         v
 1    2000       1
 2    2003       3
 3    2005       3
 4    2006       6
 5    2009       1
 6    2011       1
 7    2013       3",header=TRUE)

DF <- merge(DF,
            data.frame(y=seq.int(min(DF$y),max(DF$y))),
            by="y",all=TRUE)
DF$v[is.na(DF$v)] <- 0 #assuming you have no other NA values

head(DF)
#      y v
# 1 2000 1
# 2 2001 0
# 3 2002 0
# 4 2003 3
# 5 2004 0
# 6 2005 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Or `match` could be another way...

```
yseq <- min(DF$y):max(DF$y)
df2 <- data.frame( y = yseq , v = numeric( length( yseq ) ) )
df2$v[ match( DF$y , df2$y ) ] <- DF$v

head(df2)
#    y v
#1 2000 1
#2 2001 0
#3 2002 0
#4 2003 3
#5 2004 0
#6 2005 3
```